# Express not awaiting MongoJS Function

Tags: javascript, express, mongojs

I've set up a function for my Express JS endpoint to 'await' to get a result from a Mongo DB using Mongo JS.

Function:-

```
async function getIntroducer(company){


  const intro = await dbIntro.collection('introducers').findOne({company: company},  function(err, doc) {
 
 console.log(" ~ file: app.js ~ line 289 ~ intro ~ doc.introducer", doc.introducer)
   return doc.introducer
  });
  
  
  return intro

  //return intro;
};
```

Express JS Endpoint:-

```
app.post(
  "/case",
  passport.authenticate("accessToken", { session: false }),
  async function (req, res) {
    const body = req?.body;
    
    const intro = await getIntroducer(req.user.company);
    console.log(" ~ file: app.js ~ line 1152 ~ intro", intro)
```

Current behaviour, :-

```
 ~ file: app.js ~ line 1152 ~ intro undefined
```

Then the result sends, then thereafter I get this in console (aka it's not awaiting):-

```
 ~ file: app.js ~ line 289 ~ intro ~ doc.introducer 347501
```

I've also tried completely getting rid of 'const intro' and just straight returning it. And I've also tried getting rid of the callback function but MongoJS says 'CB is not a function'

Any help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mincing different styles of asynchronous implementations (callback and promise) when querying the collection.

Seeing as the [mongojs library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongojs) supports only the callback style. You need to promisify the findOne operation to await it.

There is the `promisify` function in the `util` standard library module that can aid in this goal inasmuch as the callback signature is a function that is called with an error and/or a result.

For example, to promisify the `findOne` operation so that it can be awaited, you can write

```js
const util = require('util');

async function getIntroducer(company){
  const findOneDbIntro = util.promisify(dbIntro.collection('introducers').findOne);
  let intro;
  try {
    intro = await findOneDbIntro({company: company});
  }
  catch (err) 
  {
    // log error with your logging library.
  }
//...
}
```

This gives a similar result to doing by hand. The `Promise` object is well documented on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise):

```js
async function getIntroducer(company){
  let intro;
  try {
    intro = await new Promise(
      (resolve, reject) => {
        dbIntro.collection('introducers').findOne({company: company},
          function (err, doc) {
          if(err) {
            reject(err);
          }
          resolve(doc);
       });
    });
  } catch (err) 
  {
    // log error with your logging library.
  }
    //...
}
```